# An internal error occurred during: "Checking module status for server JBoss AS 5.1". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jboss

I am getting this Exception while add Web Application through JBoss Server

Comment: Check your server.log and post the full stacktrace, there's no way anyone can guess what's happening with that little info (also consider updating to a recent version of Wildfly, JBoss AS 5.1 is 10 years old now...)

Answer (score 0):

Well it would help if you posted some of your code but if its a NullPointerException odds are you have an uninitialized variable somewhere in your codebase, can't offer much else without the codebase however.

I would guess that the most likely cause of this is that you server is not running or cannot be accessed by your code, otherwise the easiest way to to fix these exceptions is to follow these steps:
- place a break point **before** the line where the error is thrown
- run the application in debug
- go line by line until the exception is thrown, if you see a variable with a null value, which another variable is attempting to access **or** where logic is performed upon it: this will be the cause of the exception

if your interested in more information, A null pointer erxception occurs when a pointer / reference is assigned to an object with no value, there is an object called null_ptr in c/ C++ that allows for this, but is not present in Java.
see [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException) link!

Hope this helps